# iOS 5 SDK UITextView limitation / bug?

Tags: ios4, uitextview, ios5, uitextviewdelegate

I have a UITextView with a lot of text in it.  When the subview containing the UITextView is shown the UITextView only appears after the UITextView has been touched and scrolled.

Is there a limit of how much text can be in a UITextView?
Or is this a bug?

attached is a clip explaining this occurrence.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8256776/UITextView%20Bug.MOV

Comment: If there is a text limit in `UITextView` you have not hit it yet as I have a text view containing much much longer texts. Can you say something about how the text is set in the text view. And how the text view is added, etc.

Comment: At first I pastEd it from a word document to Interface builder and that give these results. Then I tried pasting the text and set it  as NSString and set the UITextView.text to that NSString in the viewDidLoad but it gave the same results.

Comment: It's really hard to try to figure out what goes wrong without any code snippets or any insight of how the views are added etc.

Comment: I did everything with the UITextView in interface builder.  I placed a UITextView into a subview then just pasted text from a word document into the UITextView.... I noticed if I made the size of the text 10 pt it is visible with out touching the UITextView...but If I change the size to 11 or bigger the text isn't visible until after it is touched.

Comment: the text in this doc is the text pasted into the UITextView  https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8256776/Disclaimer_General.doc

Comment: Well, I have tried making an test app based on what you describe and what I saw in the video and it works just fine. There must be something specific in your setup that gives this special behaviour. Could you make a small project with just the necessities to reproduce the issue and then post a link to it here. I'll be glad to take look at it, but as it is right now I simply can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have uploaded the entire project to drop box https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8256776/TestApp.zip   you can see the issue in the disclaimer and the DUI information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have looked into it and it seems to be quite a common issue. It seems that the text view doesn't feel that it has to draw the text, but calling `setNeedsDisplay` doesn't help. I don't know if there is a "real" solution, but you can force it to draw the text by scrolling programmatically:

```
disclaimerView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 1);
disclaimerView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
```

An unrelated thing in your code: In your `switchView` method you have two animations, one for the menu view and one for the view you are sliding into place. This is unnecessary as you can put both `setFrame` calls in the same animation:

```
MenuView = (UIView *)[self.view viewWithTag:100];
appView = (UIView *)[self.view viewWithTag:ViewInt];
[MenuView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[appView setFrame:CGRectMake(321, 0, 320, 480)];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"move buttons" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
[MenuView setFrame:CGRectMake(-320, 0, 320, 480)];
[appView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
disclaimerView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 1);
disclaimerView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

And one more thing (and then I will back off :) )
You seem to be quite fond of using tags to retrieve elements. While it does work, it is not very understandable. You don't have that many elements so I would just add each of them as `IBOutlet` with a meaningful name (like you did with your `disclaimerView`). Also, have seperate `switchView` methods for the different views you are moving into place. That way you can easily perform additional stuff you might need for just that view, like the force scroll on `disclaimerView`.

Comment: thanks for all the helpful hints. I didnt know that you could set multiple animations in the same block.  The reason I use using the tags is, i couldnt think of an elegant way to call a subview from one button with out naming all the subviews. All great information, thanks so much.

Comment: Funny you should say "block" because it actually reminds me that since iOS 4.0 the recommended way of doing animations is actually using blocks, for instance using the method `animateWithDuration:animations:`. Using `beginAnimations`/`commitAnimations` is discouraged, although I don't believe that they are deprecated yet.